# How to use JavaScript to add a class after clicking and then remove it after clicking again?

Tags: javascript

I just learned javascript not long ago, and I am practicing how to add color after clicking, and I can cancel the color when I click again!

But even though I checked on the Internet, I still don’t know which grammar is wrong?

Hope to get your guidance, thank you~

```js
let add = document.querySelector('.add');
let box = document.querySelector('.box');


add.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  box.setAttribute('class','blue');
})
```

```css
.add {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a class="add" href="javascript:;">click</a>

<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`classList.toggle` is exactly what you need. It will remove the class if already present and add it if not. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle).

```js
let add = document.querySelector('.add');
let box = document.querySelector('.box');

add.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  box.classList.toggle('blue');
})
```

```css
.add {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a class="add" href="javascript:;">click</a>

<div class="box"></div>
```

---

**Problem in your code:**

```
box.setAttribute('class','blue');
```

this will always overwrite the class to 'blue'

---

As you're interested in doing this using `setAttribute`, the following is one way to do it.

```js
let add = document.querySelector('.add');
let box = document.querySelector('.box');

// not recommended
add.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const existingClasses = box.getAttribute('class');
  const newClasses = (existingClasses.includes('blue') ? existingClasses.replace('blue', '') : `${existingClasses} blue`).trim();

  box.setAttribute('class', newClasses);
})
```

```css
.add {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a class="add" href="javascript:;">click</a>

<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Never knew about `toggle`

Comment: @Ramesh Reddy
Thank you for your answer, he helped me!

Because I am a beginner or I would like to ask you if I want to use setAttribute() with removeAttribute() the correct way how should I write it?

https://codepen.io/hong-wei/pen/MWEvQME?editors=1111

Comment: @AWEI `setAttribute` is not suitable here as we always want to keep the `box` class while toggling the `blue` class. `setAttribute('class','blue')` will remove everything and keep `blue`.

Comment: @AWEI Updated my answer to add an approach that uses `setAttribute`

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me so much help, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an event handler in your javascript, that removes the class again. The only handler you have is the one adding blue.

```
box.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  box.removeAttribute('class');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the `box` has a class and if so, remove & else add

You can do it like this;

```
box.classList.contains("blue") ? box.classList.remove("blue") : box.classList.add("blue")
```